# Access PHP files without extension

Tags: php, apache

I have a problem accessing php files without the .php extension.

I have several web servers where I do this, but in this particular instance it doesn't seem to work and I haven't been able to find the issue.

My config goes like this.

In the httpd.conf file I have the root set up as /web/http/v2

On v2, I have a .htaccess with the following:

```
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^/])/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule .+ %1.php [QSA,L]
```

Originally, on the other servers is was only:

```
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
```

The file is is called test, and inside has a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` , when I try to access the file as http://hostname:8081/test it is displaying the php code, instead of the actual phpinfo display.

This is my configure command:

```
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-mysql' '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--without-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-json' '--without-pspell' '--disable-wddx' '--without-curl' '--disable-posix' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm' '--disable-sysvsem'
```

Modules:

```
core prefork http_core mod_so mod_php5 mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_file mod_authn_alias mod_authn_anon mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_default mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_authz_owner mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_default util_ldap mod_authnz_ldap mod_include mod_log_config mod_logio mod_env mod_ext_filter mod_mime_magic mod_expires mod_deflate mod_headers mod_usertrack mod_setenvif mod_mime mod_dav mod_status mod_autoindex mod_info mod_dav_fs mod_vhost_alias mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir mod_alias mod_substitute mod_rewrite mod_proxy mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_ajp mod_proxy_connect mod_cache mod_suexec mod_disk_cache mod_cgi mod_version
```

I have tried a lot of different combinations in the .htaccess, tried different php5mod compilation, but... no idea why it is still failing to render the page right. With .php of course, it is working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

Turns out the new apache installer puts the following in the httpd.conf

```
  <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
```

So, all my .htaccess statements were being ignored. Now everything is working.

Comment: Just for reference, if you have access to the server-level Apache configuration, it's a good idea to put your custom settings in there (in some combination of `<VirtualHost>`, `<Location>`, and `<Directory>` blocks), and leave `.htaccess` disabled. The reason is that when it's enabled, the server has to scan the filesystem for `.htaccess` files *on every single web request it receives*, to see if they override any relevant settings. This is clearly much slower than loading the settings into memory once when you restart the server.